# Mesh grid using triangle strips rendering incorrectly?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I am having trouble rendering a mesh grid using VAOs and triangle strips in OpenGL.

Here is my code to generate the vertices and indices and put them in their respective buffers.

```
void HeightField::generateMesh(int tesselation) {
// generate a mesh in range -1 to 1 in x and z
int verticesPerRow = sqrt(tesselation / 2) + 1;
float* verts = NULL;
verts = new float[verticesPerRow*verticesPerRow*3];

//Generate Vertices
float z = 1;
int idx = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < verticesPerRow; j++) {
    float x = -1;
    for (int k = 0; k < verticesPerRow; k++) {
        verts[idx++] = x;
        verts[idx++] = 0;
        verts[idx++] = z;
        x += (2.0f/float(verticesPerRow-1));
    }
    z -= (2.0f / float(verticesPerRow-1));
}

printf("\n VERTICES \n");
for (int o = 0; o < verticesPerRow*verticesPerRow*3; o++) {
    printf("%f, ", verts[o]);
    if (o % 3 == 2) {
        printf("\n");
    }
}


//Generate indices

int rows = sqrt(tesselation / 2);
int columns = rows+1;
int* indices = NULL;
int indicesAmount = 2 * rows*columns +  rows;
indices = new int[indicesAmount];
idx = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {

        indices[idx++] = (r + 1) * columns + c;
        indices[idx++] = r * columns + c;
        //printf("%i, %i,  ", indices[idx - 2], indices[idx - 1]);
        if (r == rows - 1) {
            indices[idx] = (r + 1) * columns + c - 1;
        }
    }

    if (r < rows - 1) {
        indices[idx++] = 9999;
        //printf(", %i, ", indices[-1]);
    }
}

for (int o = 0; o < indicesAmount; o++) {
    printf("%i, ", indices[o]);
    if (o % 3 == 2) {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

m_numIndices = indicesAmount;

printf("Vertices Per Row: %i \n", verticesPerRow);
printf("Number of indices: %i \n", m_numIndices);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
glBindVertexArray(m_vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &m_positionBuffer);                                                 // Create a handle for the vertex position buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_positionBuffer);                                    // Set the newly created buffer as the current one
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesPerRow*verticesPerRow * 3, verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);        // Send the vetex position data to the current buffer
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false/*normalized*/, 0/*stride*/, 0/*offset*/);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glGenBuffers(1, &m_uvBuffer);                                                   // Create a handle for the vertex position buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uvBuffer);                                  // Set the newly created buffer as the current one
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesPerRow*verticesPerRow * 2, texCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);        // Send the vetex position data to the current buffer
//glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, false/*normalized*/, 0/*stride*/, 0/*offset*/);
//glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glGenBuffers(1, &m_indexBuffer);                                                    // Create a handle for the vertex position buffer
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indexBuffer);                                   // Set the newly created buffer as the current one
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_numIndices, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);       // Send the vetex position data to the current buffer}
```

Here is my code to render it:

```
void HeightField::submitTriangles(void){
if (m_vao == UINT32_MAX) {
    std::cout << "No vertex array is generated, cannot draw anything.\n";
    return;
}

glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(9999);
glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indexBuffer);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, m_numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
//glDisable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART); }
```

Here is a screen shot of what it looks like trying to render a 16x16 grid.

[image]

If I increase the number of rows and columns I try to render, I get more rows and columns looking the way I want them to, but the "contour" of the entire figure looks the same, having the diamond like shape you see in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesPerRow*verticesPerRow * 3, verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Appearently it expects the size in bytes, and not the length of the array (silly me).

Changing the above line to

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesPerRow*verticesPerRow * 3 * sizeof(float), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

and likewise for all other buffers fixed the problem.